# How to remove whiteouts from overlayfs uppper layer?

Tags: linux, overlayfs

I have an OpenWrt-based system on an embedded device.
Rootfs is mounted as overlayfs

```
# mount
mtd:ubi_rootfs on /rom type squashfs (ro,relatime)
overlayfs:/overlay on / type overlay (rw,noatime,lowerdir=/,upperdir=/overlay/upper,workdir=/overlay/work)
...
```

There is a number of changed files:

```
# find /overlay/upper/ -type f
/overlay/upper/etc/passwd
/overlay/upper/etc/sysstat/sysstat
/overlay/upper/etc/bluetooth/csr8x11-mac.psr
/overlay/upper/etc/shadow
/overlay/upper/etc/ethers
...
```

I need to revert them

Answer (score 1):

Remove file from overlay, and then remount rootfs.

```
rm /overlay/upper/etc/*
mount -oremount /
```